# Javascript highlight effect without onclick

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to change the div background color (highlight) without having to call the function in every input onclick?

Here is my Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(element) {
    element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9900';
}
function removeHighlight(element) {
    element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '';
}
</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-item">
<label>Title:</label>
<input class="form-text Title"
       type="text"
       onblur="removeHighlight(this);"
       onfocus="this.value='';highlight(this);"
       onselect="this.value='';"
       onclick="this.value='';highlight(this);"
       value="english"
       name="Title">
<input class="form-text translations"
       type="text"
       onselect="this.value='';"
       onclick="this.value='';"
       value="translate"
       name="title_translate">
</div>
```

Here I have to call the function in every input onclick or onselect, which sometimes conflicts with other Javascript functions on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You can anonymously bind it to that specific element:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
  this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9900';
}
```

But then you will be forced to use an `id` (better than writing the same `onclick` code 20 times).

If you were to use a JavaScript library like jQuery, this code could be simplified quite a bit:

```
$('div.form-item input').select(function() {
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FF9900');
});

$('div.form-item input').blur(function() {
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'auto');
});
```

That would take care of *all* the `<input>` elements within the `<div>`. No need for anything in the HTML. It's all done on the JS-side.

Comment: but like this he will need to write this event attachment for each input element!

Comment: You can loop over the elements (somehow, if they share a common class) and apply that handler that way. I posted a jQuery solution too to show how much easier it is.

Comment: Well, he could mix this idea with a custom [GetElementByClass](http://www.actiononline.biz/web/code/how-to-getelementsbyclass-in-javascript-the-code/) and use it on `form-text`

Comment: what if i want to use YUI instead of jQuery any ideas?

Comment: They both can do this with relative ease, but I've never used YUI. Ever.

Comment: See my version [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/NvjhT/7/). Notice the HTML is completely clean from any event handlers.